# Adding CSS class based options to TinyMCE fontsizeselect

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-5

TinyMCE 3 had a theme_advanced_font_sizes setting which supported adding font size options using CSS classes instead of literal sizes, so you could do something like "Big=.big,Small=.small" and then CSS those classes up to be a particular font size and line-height combination. https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/Configuration3x/Configuration3x@theme_advanced_font_sizes/

I'm trying to figure out how to do the same in TinyMCE 5 but everything just points me back to fontsizeselect and fontsize_formats which doesn't seem to support class definitions.

Am I missing an obvious trick here?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation, the lack of answers posted here, and my efforts over the last few days, I'm concluding that this just isn't possible in Tiny 5. Tiny 3's font size selector let us use classes instead of literal font-size styles but I'm just not seeing that as an option now. At least not with the built-in size drop-field. A custom drop-field designed to look like the native selector would probably work.

In the end, rather than creating classes for each size option and defining absolute font-size and line-height values like I wanted, on this occasion since it's literally only the line-height that I wanted to define, I've ended up styling paragraphs, headings, list items, and so-on with a line-height:calc(1em + 10px); which seems to work well. This way, my line-heights are always 10px larger than the selected font-size. The trick is to do this both for the element and any inner span's that it might end up with, since Tiny adds those for the custom font-size.

So basically, this works for me:

```
#site-body p,
.mce-content-body p {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: calc(1em + 10px);
}

#site-body p span,
.mce-content-body p span {
    line-height: calc(1em + 10px);
}
```

Using a standard fontsize_formats line in the TinyMCE config:

```
fontsize_formats: "14px 16px 18px 20px 22px 24px 26px 28px 30px 32px 34px 36px 38px 40px 42px 44px 46px 48px 50px",
```

I'd still be interested in other solutions for future reference though, because with this approach I can't for example keep the line-height at say, 30px until the font size is increased beyond say, 25px, and then start ediging it up. Using per-option classes just gave so much more control.

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE 5 has the `fontsize_formats` setting and you can still use text as suggested in the TinyMCE 3.x documentation you referenced.  For example:

```
fontsize_formats: 'small medium large alpha=8pt beta=10pt 12pt 14pt 16pt 18pt 24pt 36pt 48pt'
```

...leads to this:

[image: fontsize_formats_example]

Comment: Thanks, but what I'm wanting is for the options to add classes to the text rather than font size styles. In the Tiny 3 version, Medium=.medium for example would add class="medium" instead of style="font-size:16px". So then I could do .medium { font-size:16px;line-height:22px; }

Comment: In a nutshell, I want the font size dropfield to also set a line-height that compliments the selected size. I used to do this in Tiny 3 by attaching the size options to classes but can't seem to do the same in Tiny 5.